# AttributeError: 'TracebackException' object has no attribute 'exc_trackback' Error

Tags: python, trackback, python-sacred

I am getting the error given below from the code in Sacred's `utils.py`, please let me know if there is any solution for it.

`AttributeError: 'TracebackException' object has no attribute 'exc_trackback'`

```
exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
# determine if last exception is from sacred
current_tb = exc_traceback
while current_tb.tb_next is not None:
    current_tb = current_tb.tb_next

if filter_traceback == "default" and _is_sacred_frame(current_tb.tb_frame):
    # just print sacred internal trace
    header = [
        "Exception originated from within Sacred.\n"
        "Traceback (most recent calls):\n"
    ]
    texts = tb.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, current_tb)
    return "".join(header + texts[1:]).strip()
elif filter_traceback in ("default", "always"):
    # print filtered stacktrace
    if sys.version_info >= (3, 5):
        tb_exception = tb.TracebackException(
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback, limit=None
        )
        return "".join(filtered_traceback_format(tb_exception))
    else:
        s = "Traceback (most recent calls WITHOUT Sacred internals):"
        current_tb = exc_traceback
        while current_tb is not None:
            if not _is_sacred_frame(current_tb.tb_frame):
                tb.print_tb(current_tb, 1)
            current_tb = current_tb.tb_next
        s += "\n".join(tb.format_exception_only(exc_type, exc_value)).strip()
        return s
elif filter_traceback == "never":
    # print full stacktrace
    return "\n".join(tb.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback))
else:
    raise ValueError("Unknown value for filter_traceback: " + filter_traceback)
```

Error message:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/main.py", line 102, in <module>
    ex.run_commandline(params)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\marl38\lib\site-packages\sacred\experiment.py", line 347, in run_commandline
    print_filtered_stacktrace()
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\marl38\lib\site-packages\sacred\utils.py", line 493, in print_filtered_stacktrace
    print(format_filtered_stacktrace(filter_traceback), file=sys.stderr)
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\marl38\lib\site-packages\sacred\utils.py", line 528, in format_filtered_stacktrace
    return "".join(filtered_traceback_format(tb_exception))
  File "C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\marl38\lib\site-packages\sacred\utils.py", line 568, in filtered_traceback_format
    current_tb = tb_exception.exc_traceback
AttributeError: 'TracebackException' object has no attribute 'exc_traceback'
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace, to aid in debugging?

Comment: added the same in qns.Thanks for the interest.

Comment: That can't be the full trace. It starts with "During handling of the above exception..." What was above that? Also if you put triple back ticks above and below the trace, you can code-format it.